# How to get around strict aliasing when casting uint8_t buffer bytes as another type?

Tags: c++, gcc, strict-aliasing

I want to define a struct to map the bytes of packets received over a serial stream. The number of payload bytes in the packet is variable, and there's a 16-bit CRC after the payload bytes. (The packet byte layout, with the CRC at the end, is legacy and can't change.) The whole point of the struct is for source code that uses such packets to find the named fields within the packet buffer without caring about the byte offsets of each part of the packet. And since the CRC's offset varies depending on the length of the payload data, I wrote a method for the struct that simply computes the appropriate address and returns a `uint16_t&` to the 2-byte CRC, from which the source code that uses it can either read or write the CRC.

Here's a simplified version of the packet struct I wrote, along with the `crc()` method:

```
#include <stdint.h>

struct SPacket
{
   uint8_t  startByte;  // always 0xEE
   uint8_t  identity;   // device identity byte
   uint8_t  ctrl_bits;
   uint8_t  seq_nbr;
   uint16_t length;     // length of data[] in bytes
   uint8_t  data[1];    // placeholder for 1 or more payload data bytes
   uint16_t &crc();     // returns a reference to the packet's 16-bit CRC following the data
};

uint16_t &SPacket::crc()
{
   return *(uint16_t*)(data + length);
}
```

But when I compile it with GCC, I get this error:

```
C:\Users\phonetagger> g++ --version
g++ (GCC) 4.8.1
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

C:\Users\phonetagger> g++ -o test.o -c -O3 -Wall test.cpp
C:\Users\phonetagger\test.cpp: In member function 'uint16_t& SPacket::crc()':
C:\Users\phonetagger\test.cpp:17:37: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Wstrict-aliasing]
    return *(uint16_t*)(data + length);
                                     ^
```

BTW if I remove the -O3 or -Wall, the warning goes away, but I can't do that; my co-workers would scream at me. Is there any way to make GCC happy by altering my source code, and yet still have a member `crc()` method that returns a `uint16_t&` to the 2-byte CRC following the packet's variable-length `data[]`?

ALSO BTW... I know some of you are thinking my solution is broken on systems that can't handle unaligned accesses in hardware. I also know some of you are thinking my solution is broken on systems whose endianness doesn't match the byte order of the serial stream. Kudos to those of you who thought of that. My example is significantly simplified. In reality my struct uses user-defined type `ube16_t` (unsigned big-endian 16 bit type), but the same issue applies. I didn't want to complicate things by including the definition of type `ube16_t`.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin As I mentioned, the struct in my example is simplified from what I'm actually using. In "the real thing", the data is an anonymous union of a large number of payload types. But `data[1]` is part of that union, and it's the name that the `crc()` method uses as the base address of the payload.

Comment: Yes, using a `data[1]` struct-hack is fine, but you would have to declare a pointer to struct and allocate additional space for the size of your payload. BUT, then `data[]` would need to be the last element or your struct. OKAY, so if I get what is going on, you are creating space for your payload, and it will be allocated larger than needed for `data` in order to hold `crc()` which is then used to find the end of the variable data contained in `data[]` yes/no? Or is `crc()` just taken as the 1st two bytes in `data`?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin In the receive direction, the packet arrives in a UART buffer (a simple `uint8_t` array), and once it's there, I cast the address of the first 0xEE byte in that buffer as `reinterpret_cast<SPacket*>` and then compute the packet's CRC, and make sure it matches. (In addition to the `crc()` method, I also have a `computeCrc()` method that computes what the CRC *should* be.) In the transmit direction, I use another buffer, pre-allocated to the maximum size of any packet, and cast the start address of that buffer as `<SPacket*>`, fill out the packet, and then send it.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin - The length of the `data[]` array is in reality variable. In my struct it's the last fixed-offset member, and for the only variable-offset member (the CRC), I compute its address and return it as a reference in the `crc()` method. That way all members of the struct are named, even the one whose offset isn't fixed.

Comment: Here is what I was thinking, you allocate for your payload. `data` is just a marker address, `crc` is just your `uint16_t` reference, so your data is `(data+3)[index]` to the end. Why not reference the payload as `(data + 3)[length]` and avoid the type punning altogether? (though by virtue of `data` not being the last member of `SPacket`, you run the risk of a padding byte or two mucking you up....)

Comment: Can your function simply copy the data into a 16 bit type (via casting to unsigned char*)  and return by value? (separate read/write functions)

Comment: @Galik - You mean have two separate methods, `uint16_t getCrc()` and `void setCrc(uint16_t crc)`? Yes, I suppose that would work. I'd really rather not... I liked the idea of returning a reference to it. I wished there was a way you could tell the compiler, "I promise that the only way the bytes referenced by this pointer will be read or written is via this pointer, so you can stop worrying about type punning!"

Comment: I have worked with your `crc()` function and I can compile without error on g++ 7.4.1 using `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wshadow -std=c++14`. I don't have anything older. I suspect you are on an older debian or Centos. I suspect there are compiler version differences at play -- but I think that is the least of the problems. I don't think you can do what you are attempting without `data[1]` being the last member of your struct without invoking *Undefined Behavior*. Unless C++ provides different treatment of struct member address guarantees. I'll remove my comments above.

Comment: Given we spent an inordinate amount of time looking at this, here is the version that [Compiles with g++ without warning](https://paste.opensuse.org/8994762), subject to the concerns above.

Comment: @phonetagger Well it seems more robust to me and given that the compiler will likely do *inlining* and *guaranteed rvo* it may even turn out more efficient than returning a reference.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin - Thanks for trying to figure it out for me. I looked at your version at paste.opensuse.org and I think it's basically the same as my original version. I think the only reason yours compiles without the warning is because you're using different options, or perhaps because you're using a different version of GCC. Moving the `crc()` method to before the definition of `data[1]` didn't change the layout of the struct, since member *methods* don't take up struct instance space anyway.

Comment: Ahh, I do far more C struct work than C++. My concern was the addressing. Since you are using what is a C struct-hack, the additional allocated storage will need to be adressable at the end of the struct. With `crc()` at the end, I have no clue how you would reliably address the allocated storage. Additionally, you must use `malloc`. Attempting the struct-hack with `new` will not work (I spent part of my time with that one `:)`. I do work with a MSP432 UART (eUSCI) so I understood what you were trying to do, I just could not nail down a firm yes and how or no.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin - I see where my usage of the struct is confusing... I never actually allocate *any* instances of the struct. It's just a tool for accessing packet content by name instead of by offset, and "instances" of it are obtained by typecasting a `uint8_t*` that points somewhere in a UART buffer of received bytes, or to the start of a statically allocated `uint8_t transmitBuffer[]` for packets to transmit. In both the receive and transmit case, the buffer is large enough to hold the largest possible packet. Incidentally I've used the same technique in C, just without member methods.

Answer (score 0):

OK so Galik's suggestion of providing two separate methods `uint16_t getCrc()` and `void setCrc(uint16_t crc)` is probably a better way of addressing this issue, but I did figure out a way around the strict aliasing warning:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stddef.h>

struct SPacket
{
   uint8_t  startByte;  // always 0xEE
   uint8_t  identity;   // device identity byte
   uint8_t  ctrl_bits;
   uint8_t  seq_nbr;
   uint16_t length;     // length of data[] in bytes
   uint8_t  data[1];    // placeholder for 1 or more data bytes
   uint16_t &crc();     // returns a reference to the packet's 16-bit CRC following the data
};

uint16_t &SPacket::crc()
{
   return *(uint16_t*)(((size_t)data) + length);
}
```

...or:

```
uint16_t &SPacket::crc()
{
   return *reinterpret_cast<uint16_t*>(reinterpret_cast<size_t>(data) + length);
}
```

Comment: I think that this is still undefined behavior. C++ is not simple, and you can't guarantee anything if there's an undefined behavior.

Comment: @user202729 - I kind of feared that might be the case. But the need for this kind of thing is *so common* in protocol header processing and driver/embedded code. I see code that `reinterpret_cast`'s a `uint8_t*` to a pointer to a different/larger type ***all the time***, and very rarely does it trigger a "dereferencing type-punned pointer breaks strict-aliasing rules" warning (but as you said, even though it doesn't trigger the warning doesn't mean it's not UB). Since reinterpreting a `uint8_t*` as a pointer to a different/larger type is such a fundamental need, how can it be done safely?